# sorting notes in Google Keep - gkeepapi

Tags: python, google-keep

I've looked through the docs for `gkeepapi`, and there isn't any function that sorts the notes. The notes however do appear in Keep as the order printed here:

```
import gkeepapi
k = gkeeapi.Keep()
k.login('xxxxx@gmail.com', pwd)

gnotes = k.keep.find(pinned=False, trashed=False)
for n in gnotes:
    print(n.title)

gnotes = sorted(gnotes, key=lambda x: x.title)
k.sync()
```

I am looking to sort the gnotes by title then update it, so that when I look at Google Keep my notes are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Your `gnotes` is a local variable. You first initialize it from the original (unsorted) list of notes, then reassign a sorted version of that list instead. There is nothing to tie that local variable back to the Keep service, so I'm not surprised the sync had no effect. There is a *very* slim chance that sorting the list in place using `gnotes.sort` would get synced, but most likely three result of `find` returns an independent copy of the data. Reading the API I found code for ordering list items but not for notes. Might have to wait till Google publishes a public API for Keep.

Comment: If I am tracking this correctly, you want to sort the different notes that you have that are not pinned and not in the Trash? My knee jerk reaction was to post how to sort with the 
[sort node method](https://gkeepapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#toc-entry-16), but after rereading your question your desire would be something else.

Comment: @jason Also how are you viewing this at https://keep.google.com/? Grid view? List view ?

Answer (score 1):

Since I cant call Google notes API I use a Note replacement.

```
class Note:
    def __init__(self, title, other):
        self.title = title
        self.other = other

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.title, self.other)


gnotes = [Note('OneTitle', 'bla'), Note('Ztitle', 'bla'), Note('BTitle', ',bla')]
gnotes = sorted(gnotes, key=lambda x: x.title)
# gnotes = k.keep.find(pinned=False, trashed=False)
for note in gnotes:
    print(note)
```

output

```
BTitle - ,bla
OneTitle - bla
Ztitle - bla
```

Comment: it actually doesn't update to Google Keep if I try using the keep.sync().

Comment: Do you call this code: https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi/blob/master/gkeepapi/__init__.py#L659

Comment: @jason It is not clear to me what are you trying to do. Can you please explain and share the code.